# Why doesn't frozen-out dark matter annihilate later during structure formation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, cosmology, dark-matter, structure-formation

The so-called freeze-out of dark matter is based on a homogeneous description. However, in the later stages of the universe, where structures form, it seems very likely that the reaction rate would increase enough for dark matter and anti-dark matter to annihilate again in denser areas. If this is true, I believe the freeze-out mechanism of dark matter should be reconsidered or revised.

Comment: Wouldn't such a process interfere with continued existence of that quasi-rectangular solid spotted by the JWST & nicknamed "The Brick"?  (Regardless of this request for clarification, I really dig the imposition of something at all rectangular in a sky full of spherical or oblate objects.  Finally, something really ANtithetical!)

Comment: @Edouard I think Sten has provided a satisfactory answer. Whether it will interfere with "the brick" though, depends on quantitative studies. In general, I think even for baryonic-dense areas, gravitationally attracted dark matter still can't "condense" enough for it to annihilate since it can't lose energy efficiently. As for the rectangular shape you mentioned, I've checked the JWST image. It's not really rectangular, just an irregular shape like any dust cloud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your qualitative answer is correct. Here is a quantitative picture.

The annihilation rate for a given particle is
$$\Gamma = \langle\sigma v\rangle n,$$
where $\langle\sigma v\rangle$ is the velocity-weighted, velocity-averaged annihilation cross section (which is just a constant for the simplest models) and $n$ is the number density of its antiparticles. For simplicity we can say the dark matter is its own antiparticle, so $n$ is just $\rho/m$, where $\rho$ is the dark matter's mass density and $m$ is its particle mass. (If it is not its own antiparticle, then there is a factor of 2.) Thus, the expected lifetime of a particle is
$$\tau=\Gamma^{-1} = \frac{1}{\langle\sigma v\rangle n} = \frac{m}{\langle\sigma v\rangle \rho} .$$

At the order-of-magnitude level, the maximum possible dark matter density $\rho_\mathrm{max}$ is that for which the lifetime of a particle is equal to the age of the universe $t_\mathrm{age}$. Annihilation would bring regions exceeding $\rho_\mathrm{max}$ down to $\rho_\mathrm{max}$. By substituting $\rho=\rho_\mathrm{max}$ and $\tau=t_\mathrm{age}$, we get
$$\rho_\mathrm{max} = \frac{m}{\langle\sigma v\rangle t_\mathrm{age}}.$$

Under the standard assumption that the early universe is radiation-dominated, $\langle\sigma v\rangle\simeq 3\times 10^{-26}~\text{cm}^3\,\text{s}^{-1}$ (the "canonical thermal relic cross section"). $t_\mathrm{age}\simeq 14~\text{billion years}$. A range of particle masses $m$ are possible, but for a typical assumption $m\simeq 100~\text{GeV}$, $\rho_\mathrm{max}\simeq 10^{10}~\text{GeV}\,\text{cm}^{-3}$. That's much higher than what is achieved inside dark matter halos. For example, it's 30 billion times higher than the local dark matter density of $\simeq 0.3~\text{GeV}\,\text{cm}^{-3}$.

Answer (score 2):

I have some qualitative clue. After virializing in the Dark Matter halo, the density of dark matter still cannot match that of the period before freeze-out. Additionally, dark matter cannot further collapse into denser objects due to the lack of means to release energy. Therefore, dark matter and anti-dark matter still cannot annihilate efficiently.

Comment: I see their interaction as resulting, instead, in the bar-shaped objects known as galactic filaments:  Spheres to oblate spheres to bars.  And, such a transition would balance cooling, maybe allowing the completion of isotropy & homogeneity.  Plausible? (Yah, yah, I know: comments are not for questions.  But I'm in a rush, &, besides, I think Bababeluma might have more of a take on this than my rather trigonometrically-limited self.  Delete this whoever must.)

Comment: @Edouard not sure what you meant by "trigonometrically-limited". I don't think the formation of filaments have anything to do with the DM annihilation process. According to sten's answer, this process won't be efficiently ever again after DM decouple in the early homogeneous universe even if structure formation creates baryonic-dense areas later.

Comment: I meant that I (unlike Sten) don't know calculus.  After the posting  of my comment, I found some item claiming that the filaments are rows of distant galaxies, although I'd imagine that that's questionable.

Answer (score -3):

Because according to the state of the art unified dark matter and dark energy theory, all of dark matter is neutrinos (source: https://forums.space.com/threads/resolution-of-the-dark-matter-mystery.61868/ ) and they don't do that. They barely interact at all.